# Searching for Genetic Programming framework/library

Tags: algorithm, genetic-programming, evolutionary-algorithm

I am looking for framework, or library that could enable working with genetic programming (koza's style) not only by using mathematical functions, but also with loops, variable or constant assignment, object creations, or functions calling. I am not sure if there exists such branch of genetic algorithms and if it has a name.
I did my best in looking for informations, though the internet is poor with information on that specific topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com) has a powerful implementation of Genetic Programming. It includes problems such as Symbolic Regression, Symbolic Classification, Time Series, Santa Fe Ant Trail, and there is a [tutorial](http://dev.heuristiclab.com/trac/hl/core/wiki/UsersHowtosImplementGeneticProgrammingProblems) to implement custom problems such as the Lawn Mower (which is similar to the Santa Fe Ant Trail). HeuristicLab is implemented in C# and runs on Windows. It's released under GPL and can be freely [downloaded](http://dev.heuristiclab.com/download).

The implementation of GP is very flexible and extensible, but also performance optimized using online calculations to avoid array allocation and memory overheads. We do include several benchmark problem instances for symbolic regression and classification. There are also more algorithms available such as Random Forests, Neural Networks, k-NN, SVM (if you're doing regression or classification).